# InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token When hosting the website on repl.it

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When i test it on my machine it works super fine but not on repl.it, and i do not know what's causing the error

Some say to add a proxy but i tried it and didn't work, i've been on this issue for days and im tired of this error

heres the code:

discordStrategy.js

```
const DiscordStrategy = require("passport-discord").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");

require("dotenv").config();

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    const user = await DiscordUser.findById(id);
    if(user){
        done(null, user);
    }
    else {
        done(null, null);
    }
});

const dStart = new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
    scope: ['identify', 'guilds']
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await DiscordUser.findOne({ discordId: profile.id });
        if(user){
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            const newUser = await DiscordUser.create({
                discordId: profile.id,
                username: profile.username,
                avatarURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" + profile.id + "/" + profile.avatar,
                banner: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/banner/" + profile.id + "/" + profile.banner,
            })
            const savedUser = await newUser.save();

            done(null, savedUser);
        }
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log(err).oauthError;
        done(err, null);
    }
});

passport.use(dStart)
```

server.js

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/auth", passport.authenticate('discord'));

app.get("/auth/redirect", passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/forbidden',
    successRedirect: "/"
}), (req, res) => {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable
saveUninitialized and resave

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secrettexthere',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000 * 60 * 24
    }
}))
```